# How to deploy to Heroku using Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, heroku

I've been using Mercurial for quite some time and I'd like to start using Heroku as a deployment platform. However, they seem to support Git only. Does anybody knows how to Heroku using Mercurial?

Comment: Well, you could use `hg-git`, but the real answer is "you don't".

Comment: [This post](http://www.fantomfactory.org/articles/using-mercurial-and-git-in-harmony) from 2014-05 describes how to work in Mercurial while using Git only for pushing to Heroku.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Once you have installed the [Hg-Git mercurial plugin](http://hg-git.github.com/), add an alias to the `.hg/hgrc` of your repository:

```
[alias]
push-heroku = push git+ssh://git@heroku.com:<app name>.git
```

You are now able to push your application to Heroku:

```
hg push-heroku
```

Be aware that [Heroku does not link your repository name with the remote Heroku app name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10045169/343834) by default.

Comment: When I do that, it tries to push to `git+ssh://git@heroku.com:<app name>.git/` (note that trailing slash). I *think* that's the reason I get the following:
    !  Invalid path.
    !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.

Comment: You're hit by [this bug](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/226) so you need to install a recent version of hg-git from the github repo because you need this [commit](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/commit/ed4cbf893ca9287ce6a82b970dbea08565f3dbc9).

Comment: I'm hit by the trailing slash bug and neither the latest versions of `https://github.com/schacon/hg-git` nor `https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git` work. I'm Win7 64bit with 64bit TortoiseHg 2.9.2. Does anyone know of a definitive hg-giti version that solves this issue?

Comment: I would open a new issue upstream if the bug reappeared.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Hg-Git Mercurial Plugin](http://hg-git.github.com/)

Comment: Thank you Manfred. Even with the Hg-Git mercurial plugin (the one included with TortoiseHg), I can't get my project to deploy.

Comment: hm.. but then you have a normal git repo .. it should work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use hg-git and add this to the repository's .hg/hgrc file under [paths]:

```
heroku = https://git.heroku.com/<app-name>.git
```

Now you can deploy by typing:

```
hg push heroku
```

It will prompt for username and password.  These were stored in your ~/.netrc file when you ran heroku login (don't try to use your heroku account password, it won't work).  Copy and paste from there.  See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication for more information about authentication.

Comment: This is some obscure knowledge that actually helps solve the OP's problem. Thanks, @krupan! I can successfully deploy my project to Heroku from a Mercurial repository by using hg-git and getting username+password from ~/.netrc.