# How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app with mercurial

Tags: django, deployment, mercurial, heroku, hg-git

I have an existing Django app on Bitbucket and I'm able to [deploy to Heroku whith `hg-git`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9591380/343834). Whenever i want to run some heroku command inside my app folder i get the following errors:

```
$ heroku ps
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
$ heroku logs
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
etc.
```

Current workaround is to specify the app name: `heroku ps --app <app name>` but i'm looking for a way to link my repository name to the remote Heroku app name like [how it's done using git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5129598/343834).

I'm not in a position to move my app to github for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering `heroku` is looking at the `.git/config` file to get the app name, just do the following inside your local repository:

```
git init
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<app-name>.git
```

In order not to mess your repository, you'll also add the following lines to `.hgignore`:

```
#Git setup
.git/**
```

Now, usual heroku commands no more ask for the default app name.

Comment: Note if you are using git (not this question, I know, but what I came here for), you should use this command instead: "heroku git:remote -a app"

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest trying Hg-Git's "intree" configuration option.  Set that by adding the following to your hgrc:

```
[git]
intree = True
```

With that set, the Git repository used internally by Hg-Git will be stored as a ".git" directory within the working copy, rather than nested within the ".hg" directory.

Heroku will then see this repository's config.  Add a remote as suggested in the other answer (quoted below), and you should be all set.

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<app-name>.git
```

For now, the best documentation of Hg-Git configuration options that I've found is the README displayed on the project's Bitbucket page: https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git