# how can we use mercurial instead of git to host a website in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, mercurial, web, web-hosting

i want to host a website on heroku.I Have developed it using `ruby on rails`.i have used `postgres` database and `mercurial` repository. where ever i check, i can find only ways to host using `git`.can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Hg-Git mercurial plugin](http://hg-git.github.io/) and [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591380/how-to-deploy-to-heroku-using-mercurial) on the matter.