# Pushing a Python app w/ TortoiseHg on Windows 7 to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, mercurial

I have a working Python flask app on Windows 7 with a mercurial repository created w/ TortoiseHg. How do I deploy this to Heroku?

I have tried for hours to accomplish this and ran into a variety of problems such as:

- Installing/using heroku toolbelt
- Trying to generate and use an ssh key. Putty won't use what I create with heroku toolbelt, and Heroku won't accept what I generate with Putty.
- Trying to convert my repository to git

I have spent hours on this and gotten nowhere. I understand this is a stupid, basic question, and someone might say I shouldn't bother pushing anything to anywhere if I don't know how to make an ssh key, but the alternative is for me to set up an entire server from scratch which seems even more illogical. Heroku is supposed to make hosting an app easy. Why is it I can find step by step instructions to launching an app from a blank Ubuntu install in ten minutes but this takes forever?

Comment: I haven't used Heroku, but it seems like your problems have more to do with git and ssh keys anyway.  I think you'll need to be more specific of what the problems you are seeing or just go read a git tutorial.

Comment: I already have a mercurial repository. Do I need to throw it in the trash and only use git in order to use Heroku?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591380/how-to-deploy-to-heroku-using-mercurial